# How to delete a specific element from a numpy nd array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I am working on nd-arrays whose dimensions can vary.
I want to delete specific elements from the array given its index.
like

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
index = (0,0)
```

I am expecting to get the result as

```
modx = [[2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I have tried *numpy.delete()* but this flattens the array.

Comment: *modx* is not a valid `np.array`

Comment: When you used `np.delete` did you supply an `axis` parameter?  Or did you use the function without read its docs :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not considered a good practice to *remove* elements from `numpy.array`.
As @Michael Szczesny pointed out, your desired solution is not a valid `numpy.array`.

Even if you remove elements in a way that is valid, the improvement in speed and memory usage of `numpy.array` does not justify the extra overhead to resize the array, especially if you need to remove elements often.

Instead, try to set the value to something considered invalid in your use case. For example, empty cells in a `9x9` sudoku grid can be represented by seting them to `0` or `-1`. It's much faster and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
index = (0,0)
x[index[0]].pop(index[1])
x  # this will return [[2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Does this work ?

Comment: no, because I have to generalize this method for arrays of varying dimension.

Comment: Allwin, you provided a list example - both input and result.  This not a valid `numpy` task or question.  "varying dimensions" doesn't tell us much.